# Understanding the control flow using `each` and `yield`

Tags: ruby

I came across this code:

```
class RandomSequence
  def initialize(limit,num)
    @limit,@num = limit,num
  end
  def each
    @num.times { yield (rand * @limit).floor }
  end
end

i = -1
RandomSequence.new(10,4).each do |num|
  i = num if i < num
end
```

Is it the case that the `each` method is called only once and will compute four different values, and then for each of those values we execute code block between `do` and `end`?  Is my understanding of control flow correct?

Comment: Shouldn't you get the same sequence of number for a given instance of your RandomSequence class?

Comment: Your understanding of the flow is pretty good, but think of it as though every iteration of the block between `do/end` calls _into_ the `each` method to _retrieve_ the next random value. The sequence of 4 random values have not been computed ahead of time when the `do/end` block is called.

Comment: @AntarrByrd : I ran the above code and I get random values ...sometimes they are same ...but not all are same.. It takes a random value between 1 and 10.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : Thank you. That further clarified my understanding. It looks like the code block between "do" and "end" is getting passed to "each" method. So everytime it computes a value and then executes the block  and then back to computing value and executing block. It does this four times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is close. The random number will be generated, then a block yielded, then another generated, etc 4 times. You can verify this easily by adding `puts` statements into you blocks to see when they are executed.

```
class RandomSequence
  def initialize(limit,num)
     @limit,@num = limit,num
  end

  def each
    puts "in each"
    @num.times { yield (rand.tap {|x| puts "Generated #{x}" } * @limit).floor }
  end
end

i = -1

RandomSequence.new(10,4).each do |num|
  puts "in block"
  i = num if i < num
end
```

Outputs

```
in each
Generated 0.6724385316643955
in block
Generated 0.8906983274750662
in block
Generated 0.49038868732214036
in block
Generated 0.38100454011243456
in block
```

Comment: Okay also, is it correct to say that I am passing the block between "do" and "end" to the "each" method? Looks like it is functioning in that way. Thanks.

Comment: yes, that is correct. (In case you didn't see it ... I had a small error in the answer, I just edited it to fix.)

Answer (score 1):

The `each` method on the `RandomSequence` class is called once. In it `@num.times` which creates an `Enumerator`. The `Enumerator` is iterated over and the block with the `yield` statement is called (with the argument to it ignored).

The `yield` statement calls the block that's passed to the `each` method passing the value of `(rand * @limit).floor`. In your code the block is not bound to a variable, i.e you could get a reference to the block by doing:

```
def each(&block)
  #... do stuff with block, e.g. block.call("some args")
end
```

which can be useful at times.

A bit off topic, but one thing I found scary with Ruby starting out is that a `return` statement returns the flow of execution from where it was defined.

```
def create_proc
  puts "Creating proc"
  Proc.new do
    puts "In proc!"
    return "some value" # notice the explicit return
  end
end

def do_stuff
  my_proc = create_proc

  my_proc.call # This will cause a runtime error

end
```

If the explicit `return` is removed everything works there is no error... Lesson being that in ruby you should probably avoid using explicit returns.